# RadComboBox IsDropDownOpen not updating when holding tab continuous. Phantom Drop Downs

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, telerik, silverlight-5.0

I could use another pair of eyes. The scenario is as shown below. Multiple RadComboBox's on a view with property set to `OpenDropDownOnFocus="True"` so that when they receive focus the Drop Down displays to the user.

This works as expected if the user supplies KeyDown AND KeyUp for tabbing. However if you hold the tab button down then a good amount of the time the Drop Downs (which is a `PopUp` control nested in the [ControlTemplate](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/silverlight/controls/radcombobox/styles-and-templates/combobox-styling-and-appearance-overview)) don't appear to receive notification of property change. Which causes a bunch of stacked up Drop Downs to remain open until the user interacts elsewhere in the screen. See image below for a visual example;

[image]

The `True` and `False` text you see on there are just TextBlocks I floated over the controls bound to report back the status of `IsDropDownOpen` property. Notice a bunch of them still report `True`

Initially I tried to just give it a friendly reminder to update by using the `LostFocus` event to flip `IsDropDownOpen` property back to False. Which sort of works. The problem is when it's open, the Focus is transferred to the nested PopUp. So the user can't mouse to their selection, but they CAN arrow nav to it. Which obviously isn't a good workaround.

I tried to tie into it from the template level and attach off the PopUp's `LostFocus` but I still get no joy.

Again, this behavior only occurs if the user holds Tab button down continuously, and so far the telerik forums have been pretty useless. Hoping a fresh pair of eyes could throw a bone towards another route beyond KeyUp/KeyDown or something. Any ideas?

Edit PS : Of course this is a telerik bug, no I can't update their stuff to the latest at this point in time, and yes the assemblies are probably many versions behind in this instance, just need to figure out this one individual bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if anyone else runs into this. Here's what I did that seems to do the trick. I thought I had tried it but fudged some spelling apparently the first time haha.

In the control template for both the `x:Key="EditableComboBox"` and `x:Key="NonEditableComboBox"` just replace the `Unfocused` `VisualState` with this;

```
<VisualState x:Name="Unfocused">
   <Storyboard>
      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PART_Popup" 
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen">
         <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
               <sys:Boolean>False</sys:Boolean>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
         </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
   </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

The `PART_Popup` is the combo's popup, so we'll just let the VSM give it a reminder to go the hell away on UnFocused.